# Python datetime.strptime().timetuple() - 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am stuck with this problem. Using the first method works fine but if I put it in a function, an error occurs:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
tt = datetime.strptime('09:01:24', '%H:%M:%S').timetuple()
print time(tm[3], tm[4], tm[5])
//display 09:01:24
```

But placing the statement above in a function shows an error: 'str' object is not callable

```
from datetime import datetime, time
def strtime_2_time(time):
    tm = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S').timetuple()
    return time(tm[3], tm[4], tm[5])
print strtime_2_time('09:01:24')
```

what am I missing here guys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've named your parameter `time` which hides the class `time` that you're trying to create. Choose a different name.

Answer (score 4):

You have imported `time`

```
from datetime import datetime, time
```

and then in the function definition you have a parameter with the same name

```
def strtime_2_time(time):
```

which overwrites the name time. So inside the function `time` is not what you have imported from the `datetime` module (type) but what you received as a parameter (string). That's why the error.